# Write a polyglot that prints the language's name

Tags: code-challenge, polyglot

Your task is to write a program that executes in as many languages as possible, with as few characters as you can. To avoid trivial solutions, the program must print the name of the language it was run in.

### Scoring

Your program has to work in at least 5 languages. A program's score is given as:

$$\frac {\text{(number of languages)}^{1.5}} {\text{(length of program)}}$$

The highest score wins.

Comment: Would using a solution like using `print()` for Perl, Python, PHP, Processing and R be considered trivial or is it acceptable?

Comment: A can't see a problem with it. The difficulty would be switching print's input per language.

Comment: I should have given a higher weight to the number of languages... it seems choosing to have exactly 5 is the most optimal. I wonder how many languages would have been in the winner entry if the score were `n * n / length`

Comment: I was going to suggest that too.  Based on the answers provided, I don't believe I interpreted your question properly.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### Bash, C, C++, Obj-C, Obj-C++, Perl, PHP, Ruby, 183 chars

score ~ 0.1236

For the C and C-like codes I owe a debt to @baby-rabbit. The others are inspired by the recognition that many languages have an `eval` statement that will grudgingly accept invalid syntax.

Outputs the language name to standard output. Sometimes generates a lot of error messages on standard error, so suppress them with `2>/dev/null` as you run them.

```
#if 0
'PHP<?/*';eval "print\$=?'Perl':'Ruby';echo Bash";exit
__END__
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
main(){puts(
#ifdef __OBJC__
"obj-"
#endif
"C"
#ifdef __cplusplus
"++"
#endif
);}//*/?>'
```

The php solution outputs `'PHP'` (including the single quotes), which may be bending the rules a little bit.

Last edit: shaved 12 chars from insight that `$=` is `false` in Ruby, `60` in Perl, and `print$=?...` is almost surely an error in Bash. Shaved 7 more from insight the Perl/Ruby/Bash test can now go into a single eval statement.

If the rules can tolerate more bending, I present this 8 language, 43 character solution (score 0.5262)

```
print("phperluarscriptrubypythoncatebg13");
```

for which the output includes the name of the interpreter for `php`, `perl`, `lua`, `rscript`, `ruby`, `python`, `cat`, and `rot13`.

Comment: TI-Basic supports the last one; just add 6 characters and get `print("phperluarscriptrubypythontibasicatebg13");`

Comment: @Timtech no, TI-Basic uses the `Disp` or `Output(` or `text(` tokens, there is no `print(` command. And including a string as part of an otherwise real-valued expression results in an `ERR:INVALID SYNTAX`, not the display of the string (not even as a return value). (Also, there is no `;`; TI-Basic uses `:`)

Comment: @AJMansfield Too true, how could I forget :?

Comment: Can you replace `echo Bash` with `ps -ocomm= -p$$`?  This will output the name of the shell for at least bash, zsh, ksh, csh and tcsh, maybe others.

Answer (score 20):

## C, C++, BF, BASH and Ruby; 280 chars

Score is about 0.040

```
#include "stdio.h"
#define s "C"
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define s "C++"
#endif
#ifndef s
#"+++++++++[>++++++++++>+++++++++<<-]>>-.<++++.>-.++++++++.<----.>---.<+++++++.>---.++++++++.<<++++++++++.[-]"
if [ 1 == 2 ];then
puts "Ruby"
exit
fi
echo "BASH"
exit
end
#endif
main(){puts(s);}
```

Note that I am using a Linux system.

The code is run or compiled with the following commands (the file's name is `test.c`)

C:

```
gcc test.c
```

When run with `./a.out`, output is `C`

C++:

```
c++ test.c
```

When run with `./a.out`, output is `C++`

BASH:

```
./test.c
```

Outputs: `BASH`

Ruby:

```
ruby test.c
```

Outputs: `Ruby`

BrainF***:

Verified using the following:

- [A JS debugger](http://www.lordalcol.com/brainfuckjs/)
- [A free interpreter](https://github.com/apankrat/bff)
- [My interpreter](https://github.com/mjgpy3/Brainf___Interpreter)

Outputs: `brainfuck`

Note that if the JS debugger is used, then the first two minus signs need to be removed. They were included to offset the plus signs in the string literal `"C++"`. This was a very fun project, I'm working on adding more languages.

Just to add further clarity, here are my interpreter's/compiler's specs:

- gcc version 4.6.3
- ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
- GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

**SIDE NOTE**

Using @baby-rabbit's trick I was able to extend my code to be executable in 7 languages (objective-C and objective-c++ being added). This is not my solution since I did copy some, but I thought I would show it off.

**Update 9.12**
Added SmallTalk run with gnu-smalltalk!

**SmallTalk, C, C++, Objective-C, Objective-C++, BASH, BF, Ruby; 384 chars (Score: 0.059)**

```
#if (a)
##(true) ifTrue: ['SmallTalk' printNl]
##(ObjectMemory quit)
#"+++++++++++[>++++++++++>+++++++++<<-]>>-.<++++.>-.++++++++.<----.>---.<+++++++.>---.++++++++.<<++++++++++.[-]"
if [ 1 == 2 ];then
puts 'Ruby'
exit
fi
echo 'BASH'
exit
end
=begin
#endif
#include "stdio.h"
main(){puts(
#ifdef __OBJC__
"Objective-"
#endif
"C"
#ifdef __cplusplus
"++"
#endif
);}
#ifdef b
=end
#endif
```

In the above code you will need to rename the file to produce the langauge's name for objective-c, obj-c++, c and c++.

Comment: would it be shorter if you output `brainf***`?

Comment: Yes it would, I believe.

Comment: You should use `if [ 1 = 2 ]` instead of `if [ 1 == 2 ]`, because scripts without a hashbang are executed by sh, not bash. sh may or may not be bash, on Debian it's dash.

Answer (score 13):

### bash, c, c++, obj-c, obj-c++; 134 chars; score=0.083

```
#if x
echo "bash"
exit
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){puts(
#ifdef __OBJC__
"obj-"
#endif
"c"
#ifdef __cplusplus
"++"
#endif
);}
```

rename file and run/compile as:

- sh file.sh
- cc file.c
- cc file.cpp
- cc file.m
- cc file.mm

(where cc is clang-421.10.42)

Comment: +1 since many other upvoted answers were inspired by yours.

Answer (score 11):

### Lua, Ruby, VimL, Sed, Befunge (129 chars; ~0.087 points)

Not sure if this one counts--the sed-part is embedded in the shebang line which is arguably a hack to get around the restriction.  This also means that it should be run as an executable and not directly with `sed`.

I was lucky that all the other languages (sans Befunge) automagically ignores the shebang line (though apparently Ruby refuses to run the file if it has a shebang line that doesn't contain the string 'ruby' in it).

```
#!sed sanava;s/.*/sed/;q;ruby
--"".to_i#>"egnufeB">:#,_@
if 0
then
if IO
then
puts"Ruby"
else
print"Lua"
end
else
echo"VimL"
end
```

Sample usage:

```
% lua tmp/glot.poly
Lua
% ruby tmp/glot.poly
Ruby
% ./tmp/glot.poly
sed
% cfunge tmp/glot.poly       # Requires Befunge-98
Befunge

:source tmp/glot.poly        # from vim
VimL                         # displayed as message
```

Comment: Wow, a solution that does not include C

Answer (score 9):

## AsciiDots, Befunge-93, C, C++, ><>, Funge-98, GolfScript, lua, MinkoLang, Python 2, Python 3, Ruby, vi (0.170444 points)

```
#/* ["39-egnufeB">:|;ooo"><>"
n,n=1,1--[[],0][1]#>52*,@
"""""GolfScript"
puts"Ruby\n"
__END__
:puts{"""
print("Python %d"%(3/2*2));
"""stoDiicsA"$\<ESC>dggivi<ESC>ZZ*/
#include<stdio.h>
main(){puts(sizeof'a'-1?"C":"C++");}
//>"Minkolang"9[O]."
//^}>"89-egnuF"#[v,<]"]]print"lua"--"""
```

<ESC> stands for the literal escape character 27

I know this is an old post, but it was interesting so I had to give it a shot :P

Answer (score 8):

### BF, Bash, Batch, C, vi (163 characters; score ≈ .0686)

(`<ESC>` stands for ASCII code 27.)

```
rem (){ ((0));};true /*
rem ;goto(){ rem;}
rem ivi<ESC>ZZ'++++++++[>NUL ++++++++<NUL -]>NUL ++.++++.*/;main(){puts("C");}/*'
goto a
echo Bash
exit
:a
echo Batch
rem */
```

I tested this, as a batch file, with the MS-DOS 6.22 version of COMMAND.COM. By default, that interpreter mixes lines of source code with the output. To prevent that from happening, execute `echo off` before running the batch file.

To execute the vi code, which I have only tested using Vim, use the following command:

```
cat /dev/null > tmpfile && vi -s polyglot.sh tmpfile > /dev/null 2>&1 && cat tmpfile
```

Comment: You could use `touch tmpfile` or `: > tmpfile` instead of `cat /dev/null > tmpfile`.

Answer (score 6):

## Every Python Release, 18.37291 points

```
import sys
print('Python '+'.'.join(map(str,sys.version_info[:-2])))
```

Technically valid, if you consider all the python versions to be different languages. There are currently 116 python versions, which I believe gives me a score of around 18.37291.

(Also I understand if this isn't considered a valid answer, this was just for fun)

Comment: you still get my +1 just for fun.

Comment: [Is printing the complete version number viable?](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/z/PzO3IL@oRKG4spiroCgzr0RDPQAspaCura6nrpeVn5mnkZtYoFFcUqQDVKRXllpUnJmfF5@Zl5avqan5/z8A) (This golfs down 4 bytes and extends the possible Python versions.)

Comment: Also is this okay? https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKG4spiroCgzr0RDPQAspa5dXFKkARTWK0stKs7Mz4vPzEvLj7bSNYrV1Pz/HwA

Answer (score 5):

## bash, zsh, ksh, csh, tcsh, 15 chars, score 0.745

This one's a bit of a stretch since they're all related languages, but there are differences:

```
ps -ocomm= -p$$
```

Comment: What about dash?

Comment: @Elliota List of languages that worked on tio.run: Bash, Dash, ksh, OSH, tcsh, Zsh. bosh displayed sh and yash displayed ps.

Answer (score 4):

## 16 languages, 348 bytes, score: 0.183908046

```
#include <stdio.h>
#if 0
#replace "C(gcc)" "C(ecpp)"
#replace "C++(gcc)" "C++(ecpp)"
#endif
#ifdef __clang__
#define d 2
#elif __TINYC__
#define d 4
#else
#define d 0
#endif // rk:start print: "rk" \
ps -ocomm= -p$$; exit;
int x=sizeof('a')%2+d;char*arr[]={"C(gcc)","C++(gcc)","C(clang)","C++(clang)","C(tcc)"};int main(){puts(arr[x]);}
```

---

This works in C(gcc), C++(gcc), C(ecpp), C++(ecpp), C(clang), C++(clang), C(tcc), sh, dash, bash, zsh, ksh, csh, tcsh, rk, and SIL.

Answer (score 3):

### Bash, C, Gawk, Perl, vi (145 characters; score ≈ .077)

(`<BS>` stands for ASCII code 8. `<ESC>` stands for ASCII code 27.)

```
#define echo//<BS><BS><BS>vi<ESC>ZZ
#define BEGIN A()
#define B\
{
echo Bash ;exit;
#define C\
}
BEGIN {printf(A=="A"?"Perl":"Gawk");exit;}
main(){puts("C");}
```

To execute the vi code, which I have only tested using Vim, use this command:

```
cat /dev/null > tmpfile && vi -s polyglot.sh tmpfile > /dev/null 2>&1 && cat tmpfile
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java, Lisp, Whitespace, Intercal, PHP, Befunge-98; score =.0189

This was originally an answer to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16853/how-many-langs-can-you-hack-in).

```
 ;\\0"egnufeB">:#,_@SSSTTTSTTTL
;TL
;SSSSSTTSTSSSL
;TL
;SSSSSTTSTSSTL
;TL
;SSSSSTSTSTSSL
;TL
;SSSSSTTSSTSTL
;TL
;SSSSSTSTSSTTL
;TL
;SSSSSTTTSSSSL
;TL
;SSSSSTTSSSSTL
;TL
;SSSSSTTSSSTTL
;TL
;SSSSSTTSSTSTL
;SSL
;L
;L
;L
;public class H{ public static void main(String []a){System.out.println("JAVA");}}
;/*
(print "LISP")
;*/
;//<?php
; echo "PHP"
;//?>
;/*
#|
DO ,1 <- #8
DO ,1 SUB #1 <- #110
DO ,1 SUB #2 <- #32
DO ,1 SUB #3 <- #72
DO ,1 SUB #4 <- #136
DO ,1 SUB #5 <- #88
DO ,1 SUB #6 <- #136
PLEASE DO ,1 SUB #7 <- #64
DO ,1 SUB #8 <- #80
PLEASE READ OUT ,1
PLEASE NOTE |#
;*/
;// PLEASE GIVE UP
```

Comment: This won't work in Java; every line until `public class...` will cause a compiler problem.

Comment: Interesting... I distinctly remember testing this in a compiler and it working... or perhaps my memory fails me...

Comment: @Ypnypn Remember that "T" is a tab,"S" is a space, and "L" is a line feed in white-space, which is why it does not cause a compiler error.

Comment: Oh; that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

### [Befunge](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), [Red](http://www.red-lang.org/), [Python 1](https://www.python.org/download/releases/1.6.1/), [Vim](https://www.vim.org), [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) - 7<sup>1.5</sup> / 114 characters ≈ 0.164 score

```
'a;# "egnufeB"\\,,,,,,,@"05AB1E",q', 2>2
'a;`Vyxal`,Q', 2>2#;echo Zsh
print 'Red quit;' * 0+'Python', 1>0#<0x1B>}dHiVim
```

Try it in [Befunge!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/Xz3RWllBKTU9rzQt1UkpJkYHAhyUDEwdnQxdlXQK1XUUjOyMuIAKE8IqKxJzEnQCIULK1qnJGfkKUcUZXAVFmXklCupBqSkKhaWZJdbqCloKBtrqAZUlGfl5QNWGdgbK0rUpHplhmbn//wMA) [05AB1E!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fPdFaWUEpNT2vNC3VSSkmRgcCHJQMTB2dDF2VdArVdRSM7Iy4gAoTwiorEnMSdAIhQsrWqckZ@QpRxRlcBUWZeSUK6kGpKQqFpZkl1uoKWgoG2uoBlSUZ@XlA1YZ2BsrStSkemWGZuf//AwA) [Vyxal!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%27a%3B%23%20%22egnufeB%22%5C%5C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C%40%2205AB1E%22%2Cq%27%2C%202%3E2%0A%27a%3B%60Vyxal%60%2CQ%27%2C%202%3E2%23%3Becho%20Zsh%0Aprint%20%27Red%20quit%3B%27%20*%200%2B%27Python%27%2C%201%3E0%23%1B%7DdHiVim&inputs=&header=&footer=) [Red!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@1890VpZQSk1Pa80LdVJKSZGBwIclAxMHZ0MXZV0CtV1FIzsjLiAChPCKisScxJ0AiFCytapyRn5ClHFGVwFRZl5JQrqQCMVCkszS6zVFbQUDLTVAypLMvLzgKoN7QyUpWtTPDLDMnP//wcA) [Python!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/z/Xz3RWllBKTU9rzQt1UkpJkYHAhyUDEwdnQxdlXQK1XUUjOyMuIAKE8IqKxJzEnQCIULK1qnJGfkKUcUZXAVFmXklCupBqSkKhaWZJdbqCloKBtrqAWBbgKoN7QyUpWtTPDLDMnP//wcA) [Vim!](https://tio.run/##K/v/Xz3RWllBKTU9rzQt1UkpJkYHAhyUDEwdnQxdlXQK1XUUjOyMuIAKE8IqKxJzEnQCIULK1qnJGfkKUcUZXAVFmXklCupBqSkKhaWZJdbqCloKBtrqAZUlGfl5QNWGdgbK0rUpHplhmbn//wMA) [Zsh!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P9fPdFaWUEpNT2vNC3VSSkmRgcCHJQMTB2dDF2VdArVdRSM7Iy4gAoTwiorEnMSdAIhQsrWqckZ@QpRxRlcBUWZeSUK6kGpKQqFpZkl1uoKWgoG2uoBlSUZ@XlA1YZ2BsrStSkemWGZuf//AwA)

Answer (score 2):

This is a cheap selection of languages, but here goes:

### CoffeeScript, JScript, Mozilla Javascript (≈ JavaScript 1.3), ECMAScript Edition 5, ECMAScript Edition 3, 223 chars, score ≈ 0.0501)

```
a="undefined"
x="ECMAScript 3"
if(Array.prototype.map)
 x="ECMAScript 5"
if(typeof CoffeeScript!=a)
 x="CoffeeScript"
if(typeof uneval!=a)
 x="Mozilla JavaScript"
if(typeof WScript!=a)
 WScript.echo("JScript")
else alert(x)
```

Comment: JavaScript, JavaScript, JavaScript (≈ JavaScript), JavaScript, JavaScript, 263 chars, (score ≈ 0). you can also make it shorter `a="undefined";if(typeof arguments!=a)...else if(typeof WScript!=a...` oh and you can also try golfing it....

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight Putting everything on one line like that is not valid syntax in CoffeeScript (which is a separate language from Javascript). The others are arguable, but since it wasn't specified how different the languages have to be, I think the fact that the different implementations have different specified behaviors allows them to be treated as separate.

Comment: i also cant write a multi-line comment, the only golfing you seem to have used is leaving out `{`/`}`/`;`... the idea is to use `a` to avoid reusing `"undefined"`, you could also do `b=alert` and then `b("this is also still just javascript")`. anyway `The golden rule of CoffeeScript is: "It's just JavaScript"` (from http://coffeescript.org/), you can also use some jquery to add a sixth language....

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight Adding jQuery would be absurd, since jQuery is a library, not a language. CoffeeScript is definitely not the same language as ECMAScript. The definition of a language is a set of finite strings over a finite alphabet. The set of strings representing valid CoffeeScript programs is not the same as the set of strings representing valid ECMAScript.

Comment: Can you do `[].map` instead of `Array.prototype.map`?

Comment: Can you replace undefined with void 0?

Answer (score 2):

### Windows Batch, TI-Basic, [Golf-Basic 84](http://timtechsoftware.com/?page_id=1261), [Quomplex](http://timtechsoftware.com/?page_id=1264), and [GTB](http://timtechsoftware.com/?page_id=1309) 5*2/93 = 0.11

```
::¤Quomplex¤:"'*[]'":~"GTB":g;1:d`"GOLF-BASIC 84":g`1:"TI-BASIC":Lbl 1:End
echo Windows Batch
```

**How it works**

Windows Batch was the easiest, because `::` starts a comment. Fairly simple to implement.

TI-Basic doesn't support lowercase letters or backticks, causing it to skip the statements `` d`"GOLF-BASIC 84":g`1 ``, which Golf-Basic evaulates, Displaying the message and forwarding to Label 1, where it is promptly ended. This is similar for GTB, with its handy display character, `~`. By the way, a string with no display will be put in `Ans`. If there are no Display commands following it, `Ans` will be outputted (not the case here).

Quomplex was snuck in at the beginning because its complex syntax won't allow for much to be skipped. All it does is add `"Quomplex"` to the output, and then for the mastery of the program...

**The Mastery of the Programming Syntax**

```
:"'*[]'"
```

Pure genius. Quomplex ignores `:` and takes `"'` and `'"` as strings, leaving it to output the stack and perish in an infinite while loop (`[]`). Meanwhile, Golf-Basic and TI-Basic take the whole `"'*[]'"` as a string, because `'` is a mathematical operator, not a string operator.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `:` indicates a label in a batch file, not a comment.  It's true that it doesn't execute anything on its own, though.

Comment: @Mark True, but is is `::` (still a label though). I'd rather use it than `REM`, especially since it is required in TI-Basic.

Comment: Right - I was just being pedantic.  Also, +1 for using batch files in the first place. :-)

Answer (score 2):

### JScript, EcmaScript Edition 3, 5, 6, 2016, Node, Mozilla JavaScript (score ≈ 0.1342)

This answer is originally based off Peter Olson's answer, but minus the *CoffeeScript* (as whitespace-significant languages can be horrible for golfing).

I also added *Node*, *ES6* and *ES2016* and golfed the code a little, almost tripling the original score.

```
$=this,y="EcmaScript ",x=$.module?"Node":$.uneval?"Mozilla JavaScript":"".padStart?y+2016:$.Map?y+6:[].map?y+5:y+3,($.WScript||$.alert)(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

### PE/bash/x86/C/Ruby/Python2, 330 bytes

score ≈ 0.0445

xxd:

```
00000000: 4d5a 7544 3d27 5c27 273b 0a23 2f2a 0a27  MZuD='\'';.#/*.'
00000010: 3b65 6368 6f20 6261 7368 2023 273b 7072  ;echo bash #';pr
00000020: 696e 7420 2830 616e 6427 5275 6279 2729  int (0and'Ruby')
00000030: 6f72 2750 7974 686f 6e32 2723 4000 0000  or'Python2'#@...
00000040: 5045 0000 4c01 0100 b802 00cd 10b8 0013  PE..L...........
00000050: eb2e 0000 7000 0301 0b01 0000 7075 7473  ....p.......puts
00000060: 0000 0065 7869 7400 f000 0000 6d73 7663  ...exit.....msvc
00000070: 7274 0000 0000 4000 0400 0000 0400 0000  rt....@.........
00000080: bb0f 00bd 8c7c eb58 0400 0000 7838 3600  .....|.X....x86.
00000090: 0004 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0300 0000  ................
000000a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000b0: 0000 0000 0200 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000c0: 0d01 0000 0000 0000 2e74 6578 7400 0000  .........text...
000000d0: 4500 0000 f000 0000 4500 0000 f000 0000  E.......E.......
000000e0: b903 00ba 0000 cd10 ebfe 0000 0000 0000  ................
000000f0: 6840 0040 00ff 1501 0140 00ff 1505 0140  h@.@.....@.....@
00000100: 005a 0000 0061 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  .Z...a..........
00000110: 0000 0000 0000 0000 006c 0000 0001 0100  .........l......
00000120: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000130: 0000 0000 002a 2f0d 6d61 696e 2829 7b70  .....*/.main(){p
00000140: 7574 7328 2243 2229 3b7d                 uts("C");}
```

source:

```
; nasm

base equ 0x400000

;
; DOS header
;
; The only two fields that matter are e_magic and e_lfanew

mzhdr:
    dw "MZ"              ; DOS e_magic
    jnz a
    db "='\'';",10,"#/*",10,"';echo bash #';print (0and'Ruby')or'Python2'#"
    times 64 - 4 - ($-$$) db 0
    dd 64                ; DOS e_lfanew


;
; NT headers
;

PE: dd "PE"              ; PE signature

;
; NT file header
;

filehdr:
    dw 0x014C            ; Machine (Intel 386)
    dw 1                 ; NumberOfSections
;    dd 0                 ; TimeDateStamp UNUSED
;    dd 0                 ; PointerToSymbolTable UNUSED
;    dd 0                 ; NumberOfSymbols UNUSED
a:
    mov ax,2        ; 3 bytes
    int 0x10        ; 2 bytes  ; clear screen
    mov ax,0x1300   ; 3 bytes
    jmp b           ; 2 bytes
    dw 0            ; 2 bytes

    dw opthdrsize        ; SizeOfOptionalHeader
    dw 0x103             ; Characteristics

;
; NT optional header
;

opthdr:
    dw 0x10B                    ; Magic (PE32)
;    db 0                        ; MajorLinkerVersion UNUSED
;    db 0                        ; MinorLinkerVersion UNUSED
;    dd 0                        ; SizeOfCode UNUSED
;    dd 0                        ; SizeOfInitializedData UNUSED
;    dd 0                        ; SizeOfUninitializedData UNUSED
puts_: db 0,0,"puts",0
exit_: db 0,0,"exit",0
    dd start                    ; AddressOfEntryPoint
;    dd 0                        ; BaseOfCode UNUSED
;    dd 0                        ; BaseOfData UNUSED
crt: db "msvcrt",0,0
    dd base                     ; ImageBase
    dd 4                        ; SectionAlignment
    dd 4                        ; FileAlignment
;    dw 0                        ; MajorOperatingSystemVersion UNUSED
;    dw 0                        ; MinorOperatingSystemVersion UNUSED
;    dw 0                        ; MajorImageVersion UNUSED
;    dw 0                        ; MinorImageVersion UNUSED
b:
    mov bx,0xF           ; 3 bytes  ; video page, video attribute
    mov bp,0x7C00+x86    ; 3 bytes
    jmp c                ; 2 bytes

    dw 4                        ; MajorSubsystemVersion
    dw 0                        ; MinorSubsystemVersion UNUSED
;    dd 0                        ; Win32VersionValue UNUSED
x86: db "x86",0
    dd 1024                     ; SizeOfImage
    dd 1                        ; SizeOfHeaders          nonzero for Windows XP
    dd 0                        ; CheckSum UNUSED
    dw 3                        ; Subsystem (Console)
    dw 0                        ; DllCharacteristics UNUSED
    dd 0                        ; SizeOfStackReserve
    dd 0                        ; SizeOfStackCommit
    dd 0                        ; SizeOfHeapReserve
    dd 0                        ; SizeOfHeapCommit UNUSED
    dd 0                        ; LoaderFlags UNUSED
    dd 2                        ; NumberOfRvaAndSizes    for Windows 10; UNUSED in Windows XP

;
; Data directories (part of optional header)
;
    dd 0, 0                     ; Export Table UNUSED
    dd idata, 0                 ; Import Table

opthdrsize equ $ - opthdr

;
; Code section header
;

    db ".text", 0, 0, 0         ; Name
    dd codesize                 ; VirtualSize
    dd code                     ; VirtualAddress
    dd codesize                 ; SizeOfRawData
    dd code                     ; PointerToRawData
;    dd 0                        ; PointerToRelocations UNUSED
;    dd 0                        ; PointerToLinenumbers UNUSED
;    dw 0                        ; NumberOfRelocations UNUSED
c:
    mov cx,3      ; 3 bytes  ; text length
    mov dx,0      ; 3 bytes  ; text position
    int 0x10      ; 2 bytes  ; print text
    jmp $         ; 2 bytes  ; enter infinite loop

    dw 0                        ; NumberOfLinenumbers UNUSED
    dd 0                        ; Characteristics UNUSED

;
; Code section data
;

align 4, db 0

code:

;
; Entry point
;

bits 32
start:
    push base + PE
    call [base + puts]
    call [base + exit]

;
; Import address table (array of IMAGE_THUNK_DATA structures)
;

iat:
puts:   dd puts_                ; Import puts by name
exit:   dd exit_                ; Import exit by name
        dd 0                    ; terminator

;
; Import table (array of IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR structures)
;

idata:
    dd 0                        ; OriginalFirstThunk UNUSED
    dd 0                        ; TimeDateStamp UNUSED
    dd 0                        ; ForwarderChain UNUSED
    dd crt                      ; Name
    dd iat                      ; FirstThunk
    times 5 dd 0                ; terminator

codesize equ $ - code

db "*/",13,"main(){puts(",34,"C",34,");}"
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##pZTda9swEMDf@1ccKdRtoaq@T07YKHR9W6HsaZS9WLa1BNYkpM5I2fa3ZydLiduwbmPTw1kn3f18H5J89TjdbjebBi5W8BbCUVtPF3Axh5GnnTHEMZoARO357nXayruf6xouNjUEODkBdlmxxbobbD@s/dNAWpEGYQJxe7C5e@qmi7kcJ5tl0iBstzyPMejGVIBGa1CNRDA1CYnKA6@kAhlkFWcIcHu/fvem@FQUE3Z8ec6Ko0QQxFDeGrDKOrBBcrDSCsCoSh4ZkYYcJcCkj6zP@riYLFeZIYlhS9sCanKXThFDkGp1jEgiwSWWBJIlwGzewSmv5k0RK1CcZYaKjEA/IXMOWKIG62wA26q4RnFosoJoCrBYFbk0xfEVYywzNDEM1yZZ6ZoLoPw4eMclrdUNCO4dzYQCuLth7D0bRmYYYrRetomB/T9VBPko0holhBqJEf2W2X@57h4zwxKDp2ipsOhsSfakhn0GtiF3tDYx2s2s6xkPj1/rzEBioKQq8L1TKoDeqcMMVr371WEujhje80BWvgFXY02pGffME51yoGxk9I7f2cf42Ti7Y5Qpl10cYv/3Qah9HOxgZEY11OOP4jWGf8mQ/8KoI6PZ9XEQso2nzaBLbTpgdO2mGxhNvHNmZzV09FdrcJMRNy/jaGNfSq5iX6pkWjeCU3NC@7e5hHhfnI5WvQgBhOkP/DPVJBWmV/lwZHmUr35fU1PtD6v4XU3vybM6jEOIV3tr672a7@GQy5cXDPn/50OoAwa9ezLwhm4aZdU/TtLR84Med4zzS/ZQzeanZ9@WmRHfDzR0FlBJevykpsdPkpPy2MDhoOt@OroenU1@/AQ)
in bash/C/Ruby/Python2.
Portable Executable `polyglot.exe` was tested on Windows 10 2004 64-bit and Windows XP SP3 32-bit.
Raw x86 was tested in QEMU 6.2.0: `qemu-system-x86_64 -no-fd-bootchk -fda polyglot`.

Inspired by/based on [αcτµαlly pδrταblε εxεcµταblε](https://justine.lol/ape.html), which is a PE/bash/x86 polyglot.
Also based on [this hello world PE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world/229974#229974).

##### Portable Executable

Main differences from [hello world](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world/229974#229974):

- DOS and NT headers don't overlap here, NT header immediately follows DOS header
- `puts` and `exit` are imported by name

As mentioned in hello world PE answer, the minimal distance between the start of NT headers and end of file on Windows 10 is 264 bytes,
so minimal PE file size with non-overlapping DOS and NT headers on Windows 10 is 64+264=328 bytes (64 == sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER)).
It means that all but 2 bytes of C code at the end of the file are required for this file to work on Windows 10.

The program prints its own PE signature, which is kinda cute.

##### x86

[αpε](https://justine.lol/ape.html) uses `jno 0x4a` `jo 0x4a` to jump to the main boot code. I ran out of space in the DOS header
and didn't want to rearrange the code, so I use the less robust single `jnz a` instruction. This means I rely on BIOS to not set
`bp` to `1` before calling boot sector (`M` in `MZ` is `dec bp`). QEMU and Bochs set `bp` to `0`. Unconditional `jmp` is not used
because its code is [`0xEB`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jmp), on the other hand almost all short conditional jumps have ASCII
codes, see [here](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html).

Main code:

```
    mov ax,2
    int 0x10            ; clear screen
    
    mov ax,0x1300
    mov bx,0xF          ; video page, video attribute
    mov bp,0x7C00+x86
    mov cx,3            ; text length
    mov dx,0            ; text position
    int 0x10            ; print text
    
    jmp $               ; enter infinite loop
    
    x86: db "x86"
```

This code is split into 3 parts (`a:`,`b:`,`c:`) to fit inside unused fields of NT headers.
It looks like both `b` and `c` would fit inside section header, but it breaks PE on Windows XP for some reason.

##### bash/C/Ruby/Python2

```
MZuD='\'';
#/*
';echo bash #';print (0and'Ruby')or'Python2'# ... */␍main(){puts("C");}
```

Pretty standard stuff:

- bash: `\` inside `''` does not escape
- C: allows single `#` on a line
- Ruby: `0` is truthy

Also, I used the fact that C treats `\r` as newline, unlike bash/Ruby/Python2 ([link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot/247860#comment537518_236685)).
This allows to use just `#` in bash/Ruby/Python2 to comment out the rest of the polyglot.

Answer (score 1):

## JScript, EcmaScript Edition 3, 5, 6, 2016, 2017, Node, Mozilla JavaScript (score = .174193548387), CoffeeScript (as whitespace-significant languages can be horrible for golfing).

```
$=this,y="EcmaScript ",($.WScript||alert)(x=Object.values?y+2017:$.module?"Node":$.uneval?"Mozilla JavaScript":[].includes?y+2016:$.Map?y+6:[].map?y+5:y+3)
```