# Build a polyglot for Hello World

Tags: code-golf, hello-world, polyglot

Produce a text file that prints "Hello World!" in as many programming languages as possible when compiled/interpreted, while also being as short as possible.

The score for your submission is calculated as `C / 2 ^ ((L - 1) / 4)`, where "C" is the length of the text file in characters and "L" is the number of languages that the program is valid in. Lowest score wins, of course.

Comment: This question is similar to [this other one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7261/write-a-polyglot-that-prints-the-languages-name), but in this case, you can share "Hello World" among some languages if you wish.

Comment: Does it have to be a whole program or just a valid command?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
print("Hello World!")
```

Works in at least  Julia, Perl, PHP, Python2, Python3, Qbasic, R, Ruby ...

Comment: It also works in R and Julia (and surely in many other languages).

Comment: works in PHP too

Comment: This [`print()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx) syntax is also valid in Transact-SQL. http://pastebin.com/is2mqRJC

Comment: @jdstankosky, that exact code not works in PHP. http://pastebin.com/9x6HactK

Comment: Kind of forcing the limits, but we can say it works in JavaScript too, as some command line interpreters provide `print()` function for outputting. http://pastebin.com/6fXtgFER

Comment: @manatwork Well, `<?php print("Hello World!") ?>` since you want to get specific, but I'm not counting the `<?php ?>` tags.

Comment: Works in TI-Basic too.

Comment: works in lua too

Comment: @gnibbler, doesn't work in PHP without the opening tags.

Comment: Works in Perl 6 too

Comment: Works in all derivatives of H9+ except for FISHQ9+ too

Comment: Assuming it is valid in the 8 languages listed, the score is at most(as in numerically) 21/2^((8-1)/4)=6.2433373537642856

Comment: It will print something out in browser JS, but not quite the intended text ;)

Comment: Works in JavaScript (V8)

Answer (score 17):

## JavaScript ES6, [Oration](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Assorted-Programming-Languages/tree/master/oration), [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), [Minkolang](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=) score = 71.94703045766462

`121 / 2^(3/4)`. Fun fact? I'm not trying to win, just to add as many languages as possible.

```
222 //X>"!dlroW olleH"Z 
shush=0
alert("Hello World!")
sorry=`
listen
capture Hello World!`
$$$
=` >###      .O$r"!"rXr<`
```

### What Vitsy sees

"Well, I'm a 1D language, so... for now, only the first line counts."

```
222 //X>"!dlroW ,olleH"Z
222                      push three twos
    //                   divide twice
      X>                 drop the result and carry on
        "!dlroW ,olleH"Z standard Hello, World! program
```

Thanks for the cookie, Vitsy :3

### What JavaScript ES6 sees

```
222 //X>"!dlroW ,olleH"Z
```

"Let's see... You put the number `222` and then put something in a comment. Alright, sure, I'll roll with that."

```
shush=0
```

"You made a variable. Noted."

```
alert("Hello, World!")
```

"Ah, I see where you're going with this. I'll display that."

```
sorry=`
listen
capture Hello, World!`
```

"Oo! A multiline string! Now we're talking, ES6 rulez, ES5 drools!"

```
(EOF)
```

"Well, I'm done. Peace out."

### What Oration sees

```
222 //X>"!dlroW ,olleH"Z
```

"This wasn't on my notes...! Best not do anything."

```
shush=0
alert("Hello, World!")
sorry=`
```

"Oh, here's some extra notes."

```
listen
```

"Listen..."

```
capture Hello, World!`
```

"...Hello, World!"

```
(EOF)
```

"*thinks* Nothing more! Great, I'm done here. *breathes deeply*"

### Minkolang explanation

(Too lazy to create narrative. Might do later, the code took a while.) Irrelevant code replaced with `#` or omitted. Also, added comments `C ... C`.

```
222 ###>"!dlroW olleH"# 
$$$  C this separates layers C
###>### #####.O$r"!"rXr<`
```

#### Layer 1, pt 1

```
222 ###>"!dlroW olleH"# 
222                      C push three 2s C
   _                     C space; fall to the next layer C
```

#### Layer 2, pt 1

```
###>### #####.O$r"!"rXr<`
   >                       C go this way C
       _                   C fall to the next (first) layer C
```

#### Layer 1, pt 2

```
222 ###>"!dlroW olleH"# 
       >"!dlroW olleH"   C go right and push those characters in that order C
                       _ C fall to the next layer C
```

#### Layer 2, pt 2

```
###>### #####.O$r"!"rXr<`
                       <  C starts here, going left C
                      r   C reverse stack C
                     X    C pop n (n = 2), and pop top n items on stack (2, 2) C
                    r     C reverse stack C
                 "!"      C push exclamation mark (for some reason, it's chopped off C
                r         C reverse stack C
              $O          C output stack as characters C
             .            C terminate program C
```

Comment: My child is proud of your submission. Here. Have a cookie. +1

Answer (score 9):

```
'Hello World!'
```

Runs in several scripting languages, including PHP, GolfScript, APL, ...

Comment: Also AppleScript and Javascript :)

Comment: Won't Javascript include the quotes?

Comment: This works in PowerShell too.

Comment: Works in all derivatives of H9+ except for FISHQ9+ too

Comment: Probably the best answer, If you run in python shells would work too

Answer (score 9):

**Score of 0.84**

```
H
```

Works in H9+ and HQ9+.

1 / 2 ^ ((2 - 1) / 4) = **0.84**

Comment: You forgot: HQ9++, HI9+, FISHQ9+, CHIQRSX9+.

Comment: @user75200 I'm guessing those weren't as popular back in 2013

Answer (score 1):

### CoffeeScript and CJam, 46/2^((2-1)/4)=38.68

```
e###
"Hello, World!"
e###alert "Hello, World!"
```

Answer (score 1):

## ES8, Japt, TeaScript, C#, C++, C, ESMin, score: ~8.8

```
main=_=>"Hello World!"();
```

ES8, TeaScript and Japt see `"Hello World!"`.

Comment: It won't work in Hello due to extra characters.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a lot of these (HQ9, Hello, and variants) don't count because they're not "real" programming languages.

Comment: Yes they're. They're real languages. But they may or mayn't work. And Hello++ discards non-h characters. Hello++++ discards all not part of "Hello world!"

Comment: According to PPCG standards, [they're not](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073/69481).

Comment: And there's no HQ9.

Answer (score 1):

## Madbrain and [insert most BF derivatives here], <s>272</s> 227 bytes

Just posting for fun, not to win c:

```
956658555658
852224222254
************
c4993c839941
1****1**+**+
01cc70776ccc
g+11+g++*11
 c003 c3c00
 1gg* 1*1gg
 0  c 0c0
 g  1 g1g
    0  0
    g  g[-]+[-->-[>>+>-----<<]<--<---]>-.>>>+.>>..+++.>>.>.<<<.+++.------.<<-.>>>>+.
```

***NOTE:*** There is no TIO for Madbrain, so you'll have to trust me on this one. I did, however, write an (admittedly not really well-written (but hey, at least it works!)) interpreter for Madbrain, which is on the esolangs wiki.

### Explanation

Madbrain sees: (I wrote this code c:)

```
956658555658
852224222254
************
c4993c839941
1****1**+**+
01cc70776ccc
g+11+g++*11
 c003 c3c00
 1gg* 1*1gg
 0  c 0c0
 g  1 g1g
    0  0
    g  g
```

I admit, Madbrain reaches the BF code, but it doesn't do anything, so I didn't include it here.

Brainfuck (and a lot of BF derivatives) sees:

```
++++++[-]+[-->-[>>+>-----<<]<--<---]>-.>>>+.>>..+++.>>.>.<<<.+++.------.<<-.>>>>+.
```

BF ignores everything that isn't `><+-.,[]`, so it ignores *most* of the Madbrain code. However, there are some `+`s in the Madbrain code (that's what the `++++++` is), so you need to add `[-]` after that which sets the current cell to 0.

The code after `++++++[-]` is the code for printing `Hello World!`.

Answer (score 0):

## TI-BASIC and Pyth, 13/2^((2-1)/4)=10.93

```
"Hello World!
```

Comment: Also works in ESMin, Japt, Teascript, O, etc.

Comment: Feel free to write in any language you desire, it matters not when it was made.

Answer (score 0):

```
puts "Hello world!"
```

Works in Ruby and Tcl