# Polyglot "Hello world" in Fortran and Lisp

Tags: code-golf, polyglot, lisp

Simple challenge: The code must be both valid Lisp and valid Fortran, and must print out "hello world" in both.

Note: I've sunk about 5 hours into this at this point, I'm not even sure it's possible at this point...

Details:

- Must be in a single source file.
- Any version of Fortran and any Lisp are allowed (specify which).
- Smallest source code (by bytes) satisfying this wins.

Comment: Some stuff I've tried so far that might help people:
`continue` is a no-op in Fortran. So `continue; ...` will just execute `...` in Fortran, and just refer to a variable `continue` in Lisp. (since `;` is a line comment in most lisps). I haven't been able to leverage this into anything useful yet though.

Comment: @JoKing yea, you're right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build a polyglot for Hello World](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10695/build-a-polyglot-for-hello-world)

Comment: Taking a pre-existing challenge and arbitrarily restricting the set of languages in which answers are valid does not make a new, non-duplicate challenge.

Comment: @pppery I view this as a separate challenge because of how different the syntax is between the two languages. This was also inspired by a harder problem asking for a polyglot between these two specific language, which seemed impossible considering that I wasn't even able to write hello world polyglot between the two.

Comment: The hello world polyglot is not helpful too me since I am specifically looking at polyglots between Lisp and Fortran. (As @DeathIncarnate's solution shows, however, this is not as interesting as I initially thought, since his solution makes it trivial to write a polyglot for the two.)

Comment: If you would like a specific language answer to a question you can post a bounty on that question.

Comment: classic stack exchange

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/) -ffixed-form, <s>183</s> 53+12=65 bytes

```
	;print*,"Hello world!"
	;end
*(print "Hello world!")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/v/ntC4oyswr0dJR8kjNyclXKM8vyklRVOLitE7NS@HS0gDLKqBKav7//y85LScxvfi/blpaZkVqii7QvFwA)

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), 53 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74/5/TuqAoM69ES0fJIzUnJ1@hPL8oJ0VRiYvTOjUvhUtLAyyrgCqp@f8/AA)

Comment: Damn, that's clever.

Comment: I believe single semi-colons work as well, as well as just `end` instead of `end program`

Comment: @JoKing Yeah, forgot I'd used full end program because I wanted to see if it would ignore post-end stuff

Comment: You can drop the space after the comma as well I think

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso How's that for you? F77 style saving the day.

Comment: @DeathIncarnate damn, that's even shorter than my one where I gave up and used `-D`...

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso Much as I appreciate it, you may want to wait before accepting. It's only been an hour. Better people than me may yet try and blow this out of the water.

Comment: Well, now that this has been closed as duplicate I'll accept it...